# finding indexes of an element

Tags: python, list

```
this = '['123','231','34','123','34','123']'
dups = collections.defaultdict(list)
for i, item in enumerate(this):
    for j, orig in enumerate(seen):
        if item == orig:
        dups[j].append(i)
        break

    else:
        seen.append(item)
```

I have this code.
What I want to do is to print out the indexes of each element so its in the form `[('123',[0,3,5]),('231',[1]),('34',[2,4])]`
however my code produces `[('123',[3,5]),('34',[4])]`
Is there anyway I can edit my code so it produces the answer I want without changing the form of the array so the output will stay as
`[('123',[0,3,5]),('231',[1]),('34',[2,4])]`

Comment: 234 is not in your list 'this' and you have '' around your list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
In [35]: lis=['123','231','34','123','34','123']

In [36]: from collections import defaultdict

In [37]: dic=defaultdict(list)

In [38]: for i,x in enumerate(lis):
   ....:     dic[x].append(i)
   ....:     

In [40]: dic.items()
Out[40]: [('123', [0, 3, 5]), ('231', [1]), ('34', [2, 4])]
```